# Get GeoCodes from Android Google Maps App

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm trying to integrate with Google Maps application on Android, and would like to share the GeoCodes of a selected location on the map ( by clicking on that location and pressing share )

1. I'm receiving the URL in short, which I'm running a URL expanding function on
2. After expanding the URL, I'm getting the URL as follows: http://maps.google.com/?cid=8877913323339833318&hl=en&gl=us&shorturl=1

I have searched everywhere online and couldn't really find a reliable way to convert CID to geocodes (latitude and longitude)

Question: How to convert CID to geocodes, is it even possible? If it's not possible, how do we pass GeoCodes directly from Google Maps to our app rather than getting the CID.

I'm adding the below to my manifest, I'm assuming i would need to look for something other than "text/plain"

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

Any ideas?

appreciate it.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: saw your post from http://stackoverflow.com/a/41372327/1602167 , FYI