# GeoCoords from Android Google Maps SEND Intent

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps

Hello my fellow coders,

I am trying to retrieve GeoCoordinates from an Android Google Maps SEND Intent (as dispatched when selecting to share a selected location) and even after searching around and trying various approaches for hours now I can't seem to get anywhere. However, all I seem to get from the Intent seems to be a text/plain content like this:

```
Franziskaner Wirtshaus & Biergarten - Trudering-Riem, München

https://some/shortened/maps/link
```

I tried (amongst others) several approaches from:

- [Get GeoCodes from Android Google Maps App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35346550/get-geocodes-from-android-google-maps-app) (Not applicable since it opens a new activity)
- [How can I find the latitude and longitude from address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574644/how-can-i-find-the-latitude-and-longitude-from-address/3574792#3574792) (Geocoder and Geocoding REST API from Google - no suitable results)

None of the above solutions yields any usable results.

Is there a reliable way to get GPS coordinates from something a user selected in Google Maps on Android *at all*?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Alex

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.donutpond.sharecoordinates) helps you. you can copy coordinates to clipboard or open it with other third party maps

cheers